# Azure Databricks Spark (Scala) - Reading a MultiLine json with schema returns null rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have a multiline JSON file. When I read the JSON file without a schema but `multiLine` option set to true, I get records well. However, reading the file with both schema and `multiLine` option returns all columns as null.

The schema

```
val pitStopsSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("driverId", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("duration", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("lap", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("milliseconds", LongType, true),
    StructField("raceId", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("stop", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("time", TimestampType, true)
  ))
```

```
var df = spark.read.schema(pitStopsSchema)
                   .option("multiLine", true)
                   .json("dbfs:/mnt/kchirchir/formulaone/raw/pit_stops.json")
```

Json File snippet

```
   {
      "raceId":841,
      "driverId":153,
      "stop":1,
      "lap":1,
      "time":"17:05:23",
      "duration":26.898,
      "milliseconds":26898
   },
   {
      "raceId":841,
      "driverId":30,
      "stop":1,
      "lap":1,
      "time":"17:05:52",
      "duration":25.021,
      "milliseconds":25021
   },
```

Comment: but your JSON is not correct - do you have `[]` around the data?

Comment: @AlexOtt, that was just a snippet. The original file has [] and I can read without schema option

Comment: as per Priyanka's answer that sample works, your schema does not cover all the rows read, when either the schema or encoder doesn't fit you can get null values on all columns (or class cast exceptions).  Some of your rows do not fit the schema.

Comment: @Chris, You are right. duration had some values as String.  Just a question, why does it fail silently?

Comment: I've added an answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the your same code with below JSON structure -

```
%scala
var df = spark.read.schema(pitStopsSchema)
                   .option("multiLine", true)
                   .json("Sample.json")
```

```
[{
    "raceId": 841,
    "driverId": 153,
    "stop": 1,
    "lap": 1,
    "time": "17:05:23",
    "duration": 26.898,
    "milliseconds": 26898
}, {
    "raceId": 841,
    "driverId": 30,
    "stop": 1,
    "lap": 1,
    "time": "17:05:52",
    "duration": 25.021,
    "milliseconds": 25021
}]
```

The results are coming correct now.
[image]

Comment: What version of spark are you using. I don't know why this fails on  Azure databricks 12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)

Comment: It is Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12

Answer (score 0):

As you've confirmed one of the rows had a field that did not match the expected type. As it can't convert the json file in total it just returns null.  I think it's reasonable to expect this only occurs in the rows that are broken however.

It's not helpful but it happens as well with many functions and encoding, it's almost always a sign that the types are incorrect.